# How to escape special chars in variable when using makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

supposed I have a makefile with show method

```
show::
echo $(VAR)
```

It would output `foobar` when execute `make VAR=foobar show` as expected.

However, when VAR is some hashstring such as `$2y$10$Gae9mVS`, everything goes wrong.

`make VAR=$2y$10$Gae9mVS show` shows y0, but not `$2y$10$Gae9mVS`

Could someone give me some hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two (instances) of the issue here. Neither of them has anything to do with make.

Try `echo VAR=$2y$10$Gae9mVS` and see what you get.

Now try `echo 'VAR=$2y$10$Gae9mVS'`.

Then try `make 'VAR=$2y$10$Gae9mVS' show`.

Then add single quotes to your `echo '$(VAR)'` line and try `make 'VAR=$2y$10$Gae9mVS' show` again.

In short:

#### Quote your variables.

As pointed out in the comments there is one additional issue here and this one is actually related to make.

When you ask make to expand `$(VAR)` it recursively expands the variables and sees the `$` in the value as variables to expand.

You can use `echo '$(value VAR)'` to avoid this or use `make 'VAR=$$2y$$10$$Gae9mVS' show` to escape the `$` from make itself.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure you can do this in a transparent fashion. That is it requires you to know either how the variable will be used (though any used in make itself will have this expansion problem) or know that your variable needs to not be recursively expanded at the usage site.

Comment: Thanks. But still not work...`show::echo '$(VAR)'` and `make 'VAR=$2y$10$Gae9mVS' show` output `y0ae9mVS`

Comment: Ah, hm, that's make expanding the variables too. Try `echo '$(value VAR)'`.

Answer (score 0):

It will do exactly what you will get with

```
$ VAR=$2y$10$Gae9mVS && echo $VAR
y0
```

This happens at shell level; single-quote the string.

```
$ VAR='$2y$10$Gae9mVS' && echo $VAR
$2y$10$Gae9mVS
```

Comment: Thanks. but I execute the command with parameter such as `make show VAR='$2y$10$Gae9mVS'` . Still get `y0ae9mVS`.